# Social media guide for web startups

Tags: social-media, startup, guide

I'm looking for a social media guide that would talk me through all the different steps involved with setting up social media for a new website (e.g. how to create accounts on the main social media like `Facebook` and `Twitter`, how to get new fans/followers, highlight the things one should avoid doing...) The guide should primarily cover the startup phase of a website, and ideally be in `PDF` or other printer-friendly formats. Google returned a lot of results for `social media guide startup`, none of which really stood out, hence the question on Pro webmasters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know O'Reilly has a book about this: "[Social Network Analysis for Startups](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920020424.do)".

Also, there is a ton of good info on SeoMoz about these kinds of topics.

I'll say this though.  We are in the middle of the redesign of our site.  I told the designer to not worry about ads or social media.  I don't regret it.  Design for the user first, add the social elements later.

Comment: `Social Network Analysis for Startups` seems a bit advanced: do you also have step-by-step guides for creating & managing Facebook and Twitter accounts? `SeoMoz` seems definitely to be a good source.

Answer (score 2):

The [Social Media for Dummies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470289341) book sounds very appropriate for your situation. I found the first section on developing a higher-level strategy to be the most interesting part, but you should find the practical step-by-step guides in the rest of the book very useful.

However, I think I agree with @bikedorkseattle that you should leave social integration until later: There's enough work involved in building and promoting a website without losing focus on social media, which is well known to be very time consuming and hard to get right.

Comment: I might just buy that book indeed. Agreed that one shouldn't focus on social media only and forget about the bigger picture, but not looking at it at all (e.g. going live without a Facebook page) seems like a even bigger mistake.